# Simple generic function which doesn't compile

Tags: scala, generics

Please take a look at this function in Scala and tell me why it doesn't compile.

```
def alternative_identity[A <: Any, B <: Any](obj: A): B = {
  obj
}
```

I know that the function itself doesn't make sense, however I am trying to solve more complex problem and this example illustrates the fundamental problem which I have. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know what `B` is? The function is supposed to return `B`, but it's returning `A`. Are they supposed to have the same type? What is the function supposed to do?

Comment: But compiler knows that obj is a subtype of Any, because A is subtype of Any. Then compiler can infer that obj satisfies requirements for B (being subtype of Any). What is wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: What if I call `alternative_identity[Int, Process](1)` ? How on earth will an `Int` magically become a `Process`?

Comment: @PiotrNiedzwiedz - Monkeys are animals and Rhinos are animals, but Monkeys are not Rhinos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not compile because `obj` is object of type `A` and you are returning it from a function where the return type is `B`

Even though `A` and `B` is subtype of`Any` there is no way to know whether `B` is the base class of `A`.

For example, `String` and `Int` are subtypes of `Any` but they can't be used interchangeably.